# A good API for famous quotes

Tags: api, rest, quotes

I'm looking for an API for retrieving famous quotes.
I've been looking briefly at Quotes Daddy, STANDS4 and I heart quotes.

Has anyone tried a good, preferably REST API for retrieving quotes? It must be able to get quotes by author etc.

Comment: https://theysaidso.com/api works great for me. One of the most complete API's I have seen.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989487/good-quotes-api-like-quotesdaddy-com-api

Comment: Check this out- https://github.com/natetyler/wikiquotes-api

Comment: I run a quotes API:  https://favqs.com/api

Comment: forismatic is a nice Api, although its documentation is not good but you can find other help links regarding this                    http://forismatic.com/en/api/

Comment: there is another one https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/thought/uri.json?enrich=true&query=1&relatedlimit=1

Comment: check this out - http://paperquotes.com/developer-api/ more than 12M quotes for free.

Comment: @pavitran I know the answer is old but are there any docs for Forbes API? I cannot find anything online. Thanks

Comment: you can try quotebook-api here https://www.npmjs.com/package/quotebook-api, it's solid

Answer (score 32):

Wikipedia does have an API. 
So does Wikiquote: http://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php

maybe give that a try...

Comment: found http://paperquotes.com - free to use and works great.

Comment: I approve this above comment, It worked for me too.